# image path is calling from localhost in vuejs project after uploaded at the server

Tags: php, mysql, laravel, vue.js

I have built a website in vuejs+laravel and uploaded at the server. the link is : http://bioscope-inc.demo.uttarahosting.com/ . everything is working nicely, data is getting fetched from the database, but images are loading from localhost. I have changed the image path this way :
(for the slider)

```
  <VueSlickCarousel :arrows="true" :dots="true" :autoplay="true" v-if="slides.length">
             <img :src="'http://bioscope-inc.demo.uttarahosting.com/'+slide.slider_photo" v-for=" 
             (slide, i) in slides" :key="i" />
   </VueSlickCarousel>
```

When I hover on the images(for example , the category slider from the homepage), the image path includes the server path, But when I am opening the image on another tab(by right clicking on that ), It's getting  the localhost path ( for example : http://127.0.0.1:8000/images/skin.png )

Answer (score 0):

Almost all  image links are wrong.

When you hover over the images ist DOES NOT show your image URLs but the linkes page.
All images are dead.

here one example from the JScode
{staticClass:"footer_logo"},[n("img",{attrs:{src:"http://127.0.0.1:8000/images/logo1.png"}})])])

Comment: I made those links dynamic ( coming from the database ) .I have changed all image urls from localhost ( http://127.0.0.1:8000/ ) to Server (http://bioscope-inc.demo.uttarahosting.com/)  . But still the localhost url (http://127.0.0.1:8000/ ) kept coming instead the server url .

Comment: thanks for getting me that those urls( categories ) were actually page links :)

Comment: Probably you have a wrong   **base_path**  anywhere  in the react settings  as all pictures except one logo  are dead.